# How can I use ImageMagick with exec()

Tags: php, imagemagick, exec

I have some code to process image using Image-Magick Modules.
But I can't get result into `$finalImage`.
Help me! thanks.

---

```
$requetex = ' -virtual-pixel background -background black -distort arc 50 ';

$finalimage = exec("$env_path $url $requetex $DestFolder 
          2>&1",$out,$returnval);

foreach($out as $text)
{
    echo "$text<br>";
}
```

---

Comment: Don't use exec, use the `IMagick` class https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Comment: AFAIK the image magick tool don't send file to stdout, it writes to another file and when there is not errors it don't print anything.

Comment: What is $env_path? Does it include convert and the path to convert? Or magick in place of convert if on ImageMagick 7. It would help if you show all your variables. Does your hosting provider permit the use of exec()? The output image must be inside the exec() command. The result of exec() is not the final image. `exec("path_to/convert input.suffix -virtual-pixel background -background black -distort arc 50 output.suffix",$out,$returnval);`